# Как передать переменную в имя задачи ( "-name: ")?

Tags: ansible

Вечер добрый.

Как можно передать переменную от `with_items:` в заголовок задачи `- name:` ?

```
- name: "build {{ item.dir }} with cargo"
  shell: |
    cd ~/.local/src/rust/{{ item.dir }}
    cargo build --release
  with_items: "{{ rust.gits }}"
```

Выдает буквально `build {{ item.dir }} with cargo`

Хочу, что б в выводе Ansible было видно, какой проект собирается сейчас.

Ссылка на исходник

https://github.com/Hellseher/iwi/blob/master/iwi-ansible/roles/iwi-lang-rust/tasks/rust_apps.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Заголовок задачи формируется до того, как создается цикл, и он един для всех элементов.

Для вашей задачи больше подойдет параметр `label` из [loop_control](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control).

```
- name: "build with cargo"
  shell: |
    cd ~/.local/src/rust/{{ item.dir }}
    cargo build --release
  with_items: "{{ rust.gits }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.dir }}"
```